# Delete Windows 7 network printer driver remotely using WMI

Tags: windows-7, printing, vbscript, wmi, driver

I need some help with deleting network printer driver remotely on a **Windows 7 client machine** using a vbscript with an account having administrator privileges (Elevated Account) on the remote computer. The problem is that I can't delete the connected printer the user have connected. Everything else seems to work. Below is the code for the script.

The script does several things, but the ultimate goal is to physically remove the printer-drivers. The current version of the script fails since the driver files are in use. The script contains code to avoid deleting special printers. It also stops and starts the print spooler.

```
intSleep        = 4000
strService      = " 'Spooler' "
strComputer         = "<remote computer name>"
Set fsobj       = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 'Calls the File System Object
Set objNetwork      = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
arrPrinters         = Array("PDF", "Adobe", "Remote", "Fax", "Microsoft", "Send To", "Generic")

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

'   List drivers
Set colInstalledPrinters =  objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_PrinterDriver")

Set drivrutinCol  = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For each objPrinter in colInstalledPrinters
'    Wscript.Echo "Configuration File: " & objPrinter.ConfigFile
'    Wscript.Echo "Data File: " & objPrinter.DataFile
'    Wscript.Echo "Description: " & objPrinter.Description
'    Wscript.Echo "Driver Path: " & objPrinter.DriverPath
'    Wscript.Echo "File Path: " & objPrinter.FilePath
'    Wscript.Echo "Help File: " & objPrinter.HelpFile
'    Wscript.Echo "INF Name: " & objPrinter.InfName
'    Wscript.Echo "Monitor Name: " & objPrinter.MonitorName
'    Wscript.Echo "Name: " & objPrinter.Name
'    Wscript.Echo "OEM Url: " & objPrinter.OEMUrl
'    Wscript.Echo "Supported Platform: " & objPrinter.SupportedPlatform
'    Wscript.Echo "Version: " & objPrinter.Version

    if InArray(objPrinter.Name, arrPrinters ) = False then
        Wscript.Echo "Name: " & objPrinter.Name
        drivrutinCol.Add    drivrutinCol.Count, Replace(objPrinter.ConfigFile, "C:", "\\" & strComputer & "\c$")
        drivrutinCol.Add    drivrutinCol.Count, Replace(objPrinter.DataFile, "C:", "\\" & strComputer & "\c$")
        drivrutinCol.Add    drivrutinCol.Count, Replace(objPrinter.DriverPath, "C:", "\\" & strComputer & "\c$")
    end if

Next

'   Remove network printers
Const NETWORK = 22
Set colInstalledPrinters = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * From Win32_Printer")

For Each objPrinter in colInstalledPrinters 
    If objPrinter.Attributes And NETWORK Then 

         ' The code never gets here for user connected network printers

    End If
Next

'   Stop Print Spooler Service
Set colListOfServices = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
        ("Select * from Win32_Service Where Name ="_
    & strService & " ")

For Each objService in colListOfServices
    objService.StopService()
    WSCript.Sleep intSleep
Next 

'   Delete drivers
for i = 0 to drivrutinCol.Count-1
    Wscript.Echo "Deleting driver: " & drivrutinCol.Item(i)
    fsobj.DeleteFile(drivrutinCol.Item(i))
Next

'   Start Print Spooler Service
For Each objService in colListOfServices
    WSCript.Sleep intSleep
    objService.StartService()
Next 

Function InArray(item,myarray)
  Dim i
  For i=0 To UBound(myarray) Step 1
    If InStr(lcase(item), lcase(myarray(i)))>0 Then
      InArray=True
      Exit Function
    End If
  Next
  InArray=False
End Function
```

The failing part of the code is the "**Remove network printers**" - part. The script does not list the network printers that the user have connected in the user profile, but only the local printers connected to the computer profile.

Comment: Please re-read the [*Scripting Guy* article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2007/11/02/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-remove-all-the-network-printers-on-a-computer.aspx) from which that code snippet was copied. It explicitly mentions that `objNetwork.RemovePrinterConnection strPrinter` will work **only on the local computer**. You need to use `objPrinter.Delete_` to remove printers on a remote hosts.

Comment: @Ansgar-Wiechers : Thanks for the information. You are right in that it only works on the local computer and that is exactly what I am trying to get by. Right now (objPrinter.Attributes And NETWORK) is never true so the code inside that IF-block is never executed. So it does not matter if I replace objNetwork.RemovePrinterConnection with objPrinter.Delete_

Comment: I have now updated the code snippet in the question and removed a misleading part.

Comment: Can you enumerate any printers at all? What do you get when you run the following loop: `For Each objPrinter In objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer") : WScript.Echo objPrinter.Name & vbTab & objPrinter.Local & vbTab & objPrinter.Network : Next`?

Comment: @Ansgar-Wiechers : Yes, the loop seems to enumerate all local printers. The result: Microsoft XPS Document Writer Sant Falskt
Microsoft Office Live Meeting 2007 Document Writer Sant Falskt. Sant = True, Falskt = False

Comment: It seems the user who is running the script doesn't have any network printers mapped, so there's nothing to remove.

Comment: @Ansgar-Wiechers : Okay, so the WMI call lists printers that the user account running the script have connected on the target machine? That makes sense, and clarify why my script doesn't work, thanks! But it doesn't solve my problem since the script should be places on a server executed by administrators. I will try finding a solution for this, I somewhere read about a registry way of finding out what network printers the user have connected, I think I will try that instead. I am unsure about how I can accomplish the objPrinter.Delete_ equivalent though.

Comment: If you want to retire/replace printers, you could separate the user-specific code from the administrative code. Put `objNetwork.RemovePrinterConnection` in the users' logon script, wait a week or two, then run the administrative script to actually remove printer and printer driver.

Comment: Thanks, that is not exactly our goal, but I understand your point. We have a large number of client computers and the script will be used by first line support to quickly handle errors on client machines that has faulty drivers installed. Scheduling a network printer/driver cleanup every 2 week using login script is not possible here, then we will have a riot from our 6000 users 2 times a month ;). We need to target only the users experiencing problems with their printers

Comment: In that case you'll probably need to load the user's registry hive into the registry and remove the particular connection(s) from the `Printers\Connections` subkey.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that but didn't know how to simulate a "disconnect printer" action. I did delete the registry hive and restarted the print spooler, the printers disappear but the OS do not release the driver files, so I can't delete the drivers. Even if I find out what network printers the currently loggod on user have connected by reading the registry I still can't do an action simular to objPrinter.Delete_ on the printers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove a (network) printer connection of a user who isn't logged in you need to load the user hive into the registry and delete the respective value from the `Printers\Connections` subkey:

```
Function qq(str) : qq = Chr(34) & str & Chr(34) : End Function

Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

username = "..."
hive = "\\" & strComputer & "\C$\Users\" & username & "\ntuser.dat"

sh.Run "reg load HKU\temp " & qq(hive), 0, True
sh.RegDelete "HKEY_USERS\temp\Printers\Connections\server,printer"
sh.Run "reg unload HKU\temp", 0, True
```

You need to load the hive from a network share, because unlike other subcommands `load` and `unload` don't work with remote registries.

---

To delete a printer driver (after you removed the printer connection from the user's config) you need to acquire the `SeLoadDriverPrivilege` first and then remove the respective instance of the [`Win32_PrinterDriver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394366) class (see section "Remarks"):

```
objWMIService.Security_.Privileges.AddAsString "SeLoadDriverPrivilege", True

qry = "SELECT * FROM Win32_PrinterDriver"
For Each driver In objWMIService.ExecQuery(qry)
  If driver.Name = "..." Then driver.Delete_
Next
```

Comment: Perfect, this seems like the solution, thanks! I will mark the answer as the solution as soon as I have tested it